# zone-evergreen.js:2952 GET http://localhost:4200/$%7Bthis.API_URI%7D/agencias 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, api, rest, vscode

Cuando compilo en Visual Studio Code no indica ningún error, cuando voy a la consola para ver el ARRAY me da este error. Cuando levanto la API me trae sin ningún problema los datos de la base de datos. Alguien me puede dar una mano con estos? Gracias

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { agencia} from '../models/agencia'
import { Observable} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgenciaService {

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

  getAgencias(){
    return this.http.get('${this.API_URI}/agencia}');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

creo que el error está en la plantilla de texto *[Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)* has puesto comillas simples y deberían ser tildes invertidas " ` ".

En tu codigo quedaria asi:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { agencia} from '../models/agencia'
import { Observable} from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AgenciaService {

  API_URI = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) {}

  getAgencias(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.API_URI}/agencia`);
  }
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Si muchas gracias, igual me sigue dando error, pero ahora en consola me da el 404, por lo tanto tengo que ver el servidor